# How to create indices based on kubernetes metadata

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes, filebeat, amazon-eks

I am using filebeat in Kubernetes to ship logs to elastic search.
I want to create indexes based on namespaces. I'm trying to create a custom index for my different apps in a Kubernetes cluster, but this not working.
I used below conf:-

output.elasticsearch:

```
  index: "%{[kubernetes.labels.app]:filebeat}-%{[beat.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

Filebeat Kube-manifest link-  https://github.com/anup1384/k8s-filebeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom index using Kubernetes metadata. So here I'm creating an index based on pod name metadata.

logstash_prefix ${record['kubernetes']['pod_name']}

For more details:

https://medium.com/faun/how-to-create-custom-indices-based-on-kubernetes-metadata-using-fluentd-beed062faa5d

Answer (score 0):

Use elasticsearch output as given below in filebeat configmap

```
output.elasticsearch:
  index: "%{[kubernetes.namespace]:filebeat}-%{[beat.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

Comment: This is not working. I already used.
When I'm using this my filebeat ds showing error.

2019-11-27T12:52:49.108Z INFO instance/beat.go:614 Beat ID: c164e219-3977-4b3a-b149-e793b2786aac
2019-11-27T12:52:49.108Z INFO instance/beat.go:366 filebeat stopped.
2019-11-27T12:52:49.108Z ERROR instance/beat.go:877 Exiting: setup.template.name and setup.template.pattern have to be set if index name is modified
Exiting: setup.template.name and setup.template.pattern have to be set if index name is modified

Comment: Do you have any config files to setup logging on Kubernetes?
Please share it here.

Comment: here is the reference https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-create-indices-based-on-kubernetes-metadata/120525/3

Comment: verify that kubernetes.namespace value is getting collected. in your case it might be data.kubernetes.namespace

Comment: No luck, I used the same configuration to create custom index but still filebeat index is there. could you please share your Kube manifest for setup logging using filebeat.

Comment: Hi @PEkambaram this does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<source>
      @type tail
      @id in_tail_docker_logs
      read_from_head true
      tag yourTag.*
      path /var/log/containers/**yournamespace**.log
      pos_file /var/log/file.log.pos
      <parse>
        @type multi_format
        <pattern>
          format json
          time_format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%Z'
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          format regexp
          expression /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (?<logtag>.))? (?<log>.*)$/
          time_format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z'
        </pattern>
      </parse>
    </source>


<match yourTag_**>
      @type elasticsearch
      host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
      port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
      scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'https'}"
      user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_MDSA_USER']}"
      password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_MDSA_PASSWORD']}"
      ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'false'}"
      suppress_type_name true
      index_name ocp_${tag[0]}_${$.kubernetes.labels.app}_%Y%m%d ### ==> **ocp_yourTag_appName_date**

      <buffer tag, time, $.kubernetes.labels.app>
        @type memory
        timekey 10s
        timekey_wait 0s
        flush_mode immediate
        flush_thread_count 4
      </buffer>
```

This will work 100%, just change  with your tag and  with you namespace